# Posting Image, Description, Caption, Link on my own Facebook page using FacebookSDK

Tags: vb.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using the following code to publish to my own page on Facebook.
I used the auth token from the Graph api explorer.

```
imports Facebook //'using FacebookSDK from NuGet

    Dim tok As String = "CPdPx3XhS1Kw1ERYZBmikswZAZAQiKVVh8KeoTeAZDZD" 'not real
    Dim client As New FacebookClient(tok)
    Dim k As IDictionary(Of String, Object) = client.Get("me/")
    k.Clear()
    k.Add("message", "Why this only thing that works?")
    k.Add("picture", "merry.jpg")
    k.Add("description", "Now is the time to figure out why I can't get a photo to work here...")
    k.Add("caption", "Bologna")
    Dim results = client.Post("me/feed", k)
    MsgBox(results.ToString)
```

I am running this code locally from vb.2010 express

I actually can post with this, but only the message appears.  it seems to ignore picture, description, caption.

My goal is to have a caption, with a photo, and a description underneath, and maybe a link to appear on my facebook page status.

Can anyone help me?  Can't seem to find anyone on the net who has done this, and I can't believe I am the first one...

Thank you so much in advance for helping this facebook SDK newbie

Comment: Set og-tags on the url that you are sharing

Comment: what this means?  Where do I set them? hint would help...

Comment: error I get is something like: picture not in the right format

Answer (score 0):

you must give the img the full path like "http://www.domainname.com/imgs/merry.jpg"